# I have already configure autoprefixer in webpack2 in my Vue2 project,But It doesn`t work!Who can help me

Tags: webpack, vue.js, autoprefixer, vue-loader

I have already configure autoprefixer in webpack2 in my Vue2 project,But It doesn`t work in iOS8.3 Dingtalk app.In Simulator Dingtalk App,my webApp don`t add -webkit- in all flex and all less style is ignore.But i create a ios project 
 with wkwebview run my project all style is right.

My webapp running in Dingtalk:
[image: My webapp running in Dingtalk]

My configuration:
webpack.base.conf.js

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}



module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

vue-loader.conf.js

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const sourceMapEnabled = isProduction
  ? config.build.productionSourceMap
  : config.dev.cssSourceMap

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
  cssSourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
  cacheBusting: config.dev.cacheBusting,
  transformToRequire: {
    video: ['src', 'poster'],
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: 'xlink:href'
  },
  options: {
    postcss: [require('autoprefixer')],
  }
}
```

.postcssrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  "plugins": {
    "postcss-import": {},

    "postcss-url": {},
    // to edit target browsers: use "browserslist" field in package.json
    "precss":{},
    "postcss-calc":{},
    "autoprefixer": {
      browsers: ['Android >= 4.0', 'iOS >= 7']
    },
  }
}
```

Who can Point out my mistake, or give me a correct configuration,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want I'm sure, but out of the box [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) has a working configuration even when selecting no of the extra features. This is **not webpack 2** however.

I only edited `.postcssrc.js` to match your browsers settings

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {
      browsers: ['Android >= 4.0', 'iOS >= 7']  
    }
  }
}
```

and tested with a `display:flex` which resulted in:

    `display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;`

use `vue inspect > somefile.js` to output the webpack config to look at. 
A snippet looks like this:

```
test: /\.less$/,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'vue-style-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: false,
      shadowMode: false
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: false,
      sourceMap: false,
      importLoaders: 1,
      modules: true,
      localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'less-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: false
    }
  }
]
```

I know you need `importLoaders: 1` when using vue-loader@^v15  (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#postcss)  perhaps that is your problem?